# partially-remembered SF books (alien, camping, scouting)

Tags: story-identification, aliens

There's a book (and, if I remember, a sequel, though it could have just been a 2nd part of the same book) I read in the 1970s, that probably dated from at least a decade or more earlier, that I've never been able to identify or find again.

The story was about a young alien named something like Martin, Marty, or similar, who comes to Earth, and goes camping (and/or joins the Boy Scouts) with the protagonist young Earthling boy. The sequel, or other part, was about Martin/Marty/whomever returning the favor by inviting the boy back to his home planet, where they go to a perfectly-reconstructed campsite that is otherwise located in the middle of an empty wasteland. I seem to recall that there were a lot of color illustrations.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should split this off into two separate questions.

Comment: Suggest you split this into two distinct questions, one for each book.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96157/boy-who-befriends-an-alien-whose-spaceship-is-disguised-a-book-about-friendship (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

Has to be the book [*The Space Ship Under the Apple Tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Ship_Under_the_Apple_Tree) by Louis Slobodkin (the first book of the series by the same name).

- Published 1952
- Protagonist is a boy scout named Eddie
- The alien is from the planet Martinea, whom Eddie names "Marty."

Here's one of the illustrations: [image: Illustration from The Space Ship Under the Apple Tree]

You can see more excerpts and illustrations on a Louis Slobodkin fan site: http://slobodkin.net/books/target98.html

Thanks for the question -- I hadn't thought of this series in decades... used the following Google search terms to find it: [alien "boy scout" young adult science fiction](https://www.google.com/search?q=alien+%22boy+scout%22+young+adult+science+fiction)